# How to create a first period of treatment variable (for the "did" package)

Tags: r, dplyr

I am currently trying to run a DiD experiment design following the recent Callaway and Santanna estimator and "did" package in R. In order to do so, I need to obatin a variable that specifies the first year that the subject received the treatment and to get value 0 if the subject has never received the treatment.

Let's say I have this dataset:

```
subject <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C")
year <- c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004)
treat <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
df1 <- data.frame(subject, year, treat)
```

I want to obtain this:

```
subject <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C")
year <- c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004)
treat <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
first_treat <- c(2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
df2 <- data.frame(subject, year, treat, first_treat)
```

In my original dataset I have mulriple subjects, so I would like to obtain a code to get this done without the need to mention rows or column values.

I have already tried this:

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(subject) %>% 
  mutate(first_treat = coalesce(year[treat == 1][1], 0)) %>%
  ungroup
```

But the new variable first_treat appears to only capture the first year of treatment of the first subject, in this case it would be `c(2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003)`.

I have also tried this:

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(subject) %>% 
  arrange(year, .by_group = T) %>% 
  mutate(first_treat=case_when(
    treat==1  & lag(treat==0) ~ year,
    TRUE ~ 0
  )) %>% 
  mutate(first_treat=max(first_treat))
```

But I obtain the following error:  "Error in order(year, .by_group = T) : argument lengths differ"

Do you know an alternative way to get the variable first_treat that I want, or perhaps how to solve the problems with the code i provided?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways:

The first is to create a separate data frame that filters to those given years for each subject and then rejoin it back to the original data frame. Note that for subject C the new variable will return `NA` which I think is more appropriate than `0`.

```
library(dplyr)

df_to_join <- df1 |> 
  group_by(subject) |> 
  filter(treat == 1) |> 
  filter(year == min(year)) |> 
  select(subject, first_treat = year)

left_join(df1, df_to_join)

   subject year treat first_treat
1        A 2000     0        2003
2        A 2001     0        2003
3        A 2002     0        2003
4        A 2003     1        2003
5        A 2004     1        2003
6        B 2000     0        2001
7        B 2001     1        2001
8        B 2002     1        2001
9        B 2003     1        2001
10       B 2004     1        2001
11       C 2000     0          NA
12       C 2001     0          NA
13       C 2002     0          NA
14       C 2003     0          NA
15       C 2004     0          NA
```

The second is to create a new variable that satisfies the criteria for that particular row where it occurs, and then use `tidyr::fill()` to fill in the blanks for each subject:

```
library(tidyr)

df1 |> 
  group_by(subject, treat) |> 
  mutate(first_treat = if_else(treat == 1 & year == min(year), year, NA_real_)) |> 
  group_by(subject) |> 
  fill(first_treat, .direction = "downup")
```

Results would be the same either way.